# Entry in Thailand, Malaysia, Singapore using a Canadian passport and an open-jaw ticket

Tags: thailand, singapore, malaysia, open-jaw

We are a Canadian couple planning to travel to Thailand, Malaysia and Singapore. The entire trip will take about 14 days.

Thailand, Singapore and Malaysia don't require visas. Great. However, it's possible that we add / remove cities once we got there. So we will book in advance tickets **#1, #6** only (open-jaw):

1. **Montreal > Chiang Mai**
2. Chiang Mai > Bangkok
3. Bangkok > Phi Phi island
4. Phi Phi island > Singapore
5. Singapore <> Kuala Lumpur (round trip)
6. **Singapore > Montreal**

Our questions are:

Will it be an issue if we only bought #1, #6 before leaving Montreal? Since it doesn't really "prove" we are going to Singapore from the #1 ticket.

Ticket #5 will be a "re-entry" to Singapore. Is that a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I've traveled most of these countries in various non round-trip routings and no one has ever asked for a ticket or any other proof of onward journey. As  a Canadian couple you are unlikely to get the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a little bit of nitpicking with your itinerary. Your flights will (most probably) be:

1a Montreal > Asian city (Beijing, Guangzhou, Hong Kong)
1b Asian city - Chiang Mai
2 Chiang Mai - Bangkok
3 Bangkok <> Krabi or Phuket (to go to Phi Phi Islands)
4 Bangkok > Singapore
5 Singapore <> Kuala Lumpur
6a Singapore > somewhere in Asia, Europe, Middle-East, USA
6b somewhere > Montreal

Now about your question [which isn't really about visas]. If you buy only (1) and (6) you could, technically, be denied entry in Chiang Mai, as you wouldn't have, yet, a ticket leaving Thailand. However, unless you look really suspicious, you will probably be let in. I have been 100+ times to Thailand, and have never been asked for my onward ticked there.

Once you're in Chiang Mai, you're good to go. Chiang Mai-Bangkok and Bangkok<>Phuket/Krabi are domestic flights. Bangkok-Singapore and Singapore<>KL are fine, since you have (6), a flight leaving Singapore.

If you want to make absolutely sure, you can buy in advance (4), Bangkok>Singapore. With that you have everything you need to pass through immigration checks.

Comment: 1) You are right, there's no direct flight from Montreal to Thailand. But we were thinking transfer in Qatar or somewhere Europe, since going China then Thailand seems longer (?). 2) I noticed in 4, 5 you used Bangkok and Singapore as round-trip hopping point. Would you say Bangkok > Phuket > KL > Singapore would be better? Thank you

Comment: There are indeed Phuket>KL flights with AirAsia. You might look into that, and compare the prices with round-trip flights.